# Can't connect to mysql server from WEKA tool

Tags: data-mining

I need to connect mysql server from my WEKA tool for analysis some of the data. How can i make this connection in Linux platform.

I decide to use jdbc driver for this but setting up the environment is not easy for me! How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I listed the steps what found useful when configured Weka to access DB.

Installing the MySQL Driver
In Ubuntu type:

sudo apt-get install libmysql-java

This will place into /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar the jars necessary to talk to MySQL (this is actually a link to the actual jar located in the same directory with the same name + version number.)

Configuring DatabaseUtils.props
This part is very important. Go grab your favorite file unzipper/extractor utility and open /usr/share/java/weka.jar (actually it’s a link to a JAR of the same name with the Weka version number appended) I just use GNOME and point the file browser  /usr/share/java/weka.jar from there extract: /weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props.mysql. Put this file into your home directory but rename it to: DatabaseUtils.props. Open this file and edit the following lines:

## JDBC driver (comma-separated list)

jdbcDriver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

## database URL

jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://server_name:3306/database_name
server_name should be changed to your MySQL server (for example, ‘localhost’ or ‘dbase.cs.school.edu.org’) and database_name should be changed to the database you want to use.
In this file there will also be things like: “# string, getString() = 0;    –> nominal”
I haven’t exactly figured out what’s going on here but if you’re going to be using varchar(N) in your database tables you need to add the following line to this table:
VARCHAR=0 #that’s a zero not an “oh”
And if you’re using INT (int) then add this line too:
INT=5
etc…

For reference you can check the link bellow and weka.wikispaces.com
you can check this tutorial source (ubuntu) 
https://mikebasilyan.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/weka-mysql-on-ubuntu/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just made the corrections and included the links as reference. Thank you

Comment: @sb0709: Much better. +1.  BTW, if you "address" comments like I did here, the person will receive an alert.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of your posting.